# Запрос для определения наличия скидки

Tags: php, mysql

Привет.
Есть табличка с именем  `zakaz (id,user,status)` и `refferal (id,main,sub)`

```
$db->query("SELECT distinct main FROM `lnart_refferal`");
while ( $row = $db->get_row() ) {  }
```

Таким запросом я получаю всех уникальных main с первой табличке и в цикле обрабатываю каждого (где main - это ид пользователя).

Теперь мне нужно получить о нем информацию. В частности, сколько он пригласил людей на сайт (колонка sub).
Потом у каждого приглашенного проверить заказы (сколько заказов со статусом !=fail

На выходе я хочу получить: "Пользователь N пригласил S рефералов сделавших хоть 1 удачный заказ".

Делаю так:

```
SELECT distinct id,count(*) FROM `lnart_zakaz` WHERE user in (SELECT distinct sub FROM `lnart_refferal` WHERE main='1') AND (status='zakazano' OR status='proverenno' OR status='input')
```

main - это значение пользователя, которого обрабатываем. В цикле выше оно подставляется.

Запрос мне суммирует все заказы (точнее не все, а хз пойми какие), например, в сумме они заказали 15, он мне выдает 10. Но из 15 6 со статусом fail.

Это нужно для подсчета скидки.
Скидку 5% получает тот, кто пригласил 10 человек и они сделали МИНИМУМ 1 заказ.

Comment: Вместо `select distinct id, count(*)` -- `select id, count(*) ... group by id`

Comment: Тогда он начнет группировать по ИД. ИД вообще можно не получать. просто count(*)

Comment: я так понимаю, что в поле sub хранится id приглашенного юзера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю можно так:

```
SELECT refferal.`main`, COUNT(refferal.`sub`) `cnt_ref`, COUNT(zakaz.`id`) `cnt_zakaz` 
FROM refferal 
    LEFT JOIN zakaz 
    ON refferal.`sub`=zakaz.`user` 
WHERE zakaz.`status` IN ('zakazano','proverenno','input')
GROUP BY refferal.`main`
```

На выходе получим

> Пользователь N пригласил S рефералов
> сделавших Y удачных заказов

Answer (score 0):

Having используйте. Как юзать читайте мануал на mysql.com, там ваш пример как раз.